# IAM Permissions Required by StarCluster

Tags: amazon-iam, starcluster

I am following the StarCluster [configuration instructions](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/manual/configuration.html#amazon-web-services-credentials) and I would like to create a new user for StarCluster to use. My question is what are the minimal set of IAM permissions that StarCluster requires to operate?

Is the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy required (as [indicated by this](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/mlarchives/2112.html)) or is there a less comprehensive policy.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following policy to allow an IAM user to start t2.micro  instances (only)

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExtraActionsNeededByStarCluster",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowDescribeForAllResources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "OnlyAllowCertainInstanceTypesToBeCreated",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t2.micro"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToStopStartDeleteInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:account:instance/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The policy above won't let you mount EBS volumes on instances, or use placement groups, or make spot bids.  We seem to have figured out the full set of permissions needed for an IAM user running starcluster vanillaimprovements, including spot bidding and load balancer addnodes and removenodes:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExtraActionsNeededByStarCluster",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:CreatePlacementGroup",
                "ec2:DeletePlacementGroup",
                "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
                "ec2:CancelSpotInstanceRequests"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowDescribeForAllResources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowInstancesToBeCreated",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToStopStartDeleteInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:account:instance/*"
        }
    ]
}
```